# FCM token update- flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

For `fcm (Firebase Could messaging)`, We get a token using `getToken()`

I want to know,

Is the token generate one time
or
Is the token generate every time user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registration token may change when:

- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

More :

- Update from Play Store - Token remains same.
- When close the application and reopen it - Token remains same.

If you want to call `onTokenRefreshed()` you should do it manually.

Learn more - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

---

**Additionally,**

**I recommend you should record that token for the user every time your app launches. Then, you don't face any problems.**